# How to verify Debian ISO integrity?

Tags: debian, checksum, integrity

I recently downloaded Debian 7.5.0 Wheezy and managed to use the Release.sig signature to verify the integrity of the Release checksum file using GPG4Win. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any advice on where to find the md5/SHA1/SHA256 checksum inside the Release file to verify that the ISO is correct/hasn't been corrupted/manipulated. Couldn't find any help regarding this specific problem on the support sites either. I am using Windows 7 if this is relevant.

Edit: The name of my ISO file is "debian-7.5.0-amd64-netinst". Other versions can be found here (ftp://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/7.5.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) and offer an easier way to verify the integrity because of this file: ftp://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/7.5.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/SHA256SUMS. I need to find something like this in the Release file I verified.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me with this? As this seems to be a very complicated way of verifying the integrity, I'm hoping for someone with more experience than I have to answer this question.

Comment: What is the directory from which you downloaded your file? Personally, I would not worry abou tchecking the integity of that file. If there is something wrong with it, that will be apparent pdq.

Comment: It is from the official site. My version is amd64:

https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst

Comment: @FaheemMitha, if he is deploying a mission-critical system, then integrity checking is a must. I'm a bit paranoid, so it is routine for me even for non-critical systems.

Comment: Btw you can even use the installer's built in integrity checker. But only after you've verified it with MD5 before burning.

Comment: I'd like to check the integrity using the ISO file that I have already verified using the PGP signature. Just so that I know how it works.

Answer (score 12):

You need to verify that the hash matches the downloaded image, and then verify that the hash was signed by an official Debian key - as explained in [this blog post](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-verify-an-authenticity-of-downloaded-debian-iso-images).

1. Download your CD image, a SHA 512 hash, and the hash signature. It doesn't matter where you get them from, because of the signature that we'll verify below. But you can get it from [debian.org](https://www.debian.org/distrib/).
2. Verify that the hash matches the image (neither of these commands should print anything):

   ```
   $ sha512sum debian-8.3.0-amd64-i386-netinst.iso > my_hash.txt
   $ diff -q my_hash.txt SHA512SUMS.txt
   ```
3. Verify the hash is properly signed. You'll probably have to do it twice: once to get the key ID, and again after you have downloaded the public key. The command output should look a lot like this:

   ```
   $ gpg --verify SHA512SUMS.sign.txt SHA512SUMS.txt
   gpg: Signature made Mon 25 Jan 2016 05:08:46 AEDT using RSA key ID 6294BE9B
   gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
   $ gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv 6294BE9B
   gpg: requesting key 6294BE9B from hkp server keyring.debian.org
   gpg: key 6294BE9B: public key "Debian CD signing key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>" imported
   gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
   $ gpg --verify SHA512SUMS.sign.txt SHA512SUMS.txt
   gpg: Signature made Mon 25 Jan 2016 05:08:46 AEDT using RSA key ID 6294BE9B
   gpg: Good signature from "Debian CD signing key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>"
   gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
   gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
   Primary key fingerprint: DF9B 9C49 EAA9 2984 3258  9D76 DA87 E80D 6294 BE9B
   ```
4. Verify that the key fingerprint (the last printed line) is legitimate. Ideally, you should do this via a [web of trust](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x547.html). However you can check the key fingerprint against  the keys listed on [Debian's secure web site](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify) (HTTPS).

Comment: Very helpful. Respectfully suggest you add a step between your current steps 1 and 2, to read something like: **"Copy the relevant line from the SHA 512 hash (if said file has more than one line) and paste same to a new text file, named SHA512SUMS.txt."** Next, in your `$ gpg --verify SHA512SUMS.sign.txt SHA512SUMS.txt` step, suggest you change the reference to the `SHA512SUMS.txt` file such that it references the _originally downloaded, unchanged_ hash file (the one with _all_ of the original data).  Said suggested changes would have prevented me from going down a deep, dark rabbit hole...

Comment: In step 2, what's the purpose of doing it the way you've written versus `sha512sum -c SHA512SUMS.txt`?

Comment: @cdhowie no reason. Your way is better; feel free to edit it

Comment: In addition to removing other sha512sums for SHA512SUMS.txt in step 2, step 3 doesn't work: it shows `using RSA key DF9B9C49EAA9298432589D76DA87E80D6294BE9B` `gpg: Can't check signature: No public key`. How to import the key? When I replace `6294BE9B` with that longer Id I just get `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out`. Also why doesn't [this page](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify) simply precisely list all the commands needed?

Comment: I could import they key with this: `gpg --keyserver hkps://keyring.debian.org --recv-key DF9B9C49EAA9298432589D76DA87E80D6294BE9B`. If one needs to open some specific port in the nftables firewall for the other commands to work this info needs to get added! Step 4 also means checking this fingerprint against the fingerprint in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/

The netinst ISO is at http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-7.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso.

You can find the md5sum in http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/MD5SUMS.

The relevant line is:

```
8fdb6715228ea90faba58cb84644d296  debian-7.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

Comment: I'd prefer only using the ISO that I already downloaded and that I verified using the PGP signature.